Thymeleaf and macro substitution
folks...
Can I do something like this using Thymeleaf?
<tr th:each="row : ${list}">
    <td th:each="field : ${arrayFieldName}" scope="row">
        <span th:text="|${row.${field[0]}}|"></span>
    </td>
</tr>

I can use:
<span th:text="|${row.nameOfMyField1}|"></span>
<span th:text="|${row.nameOfMyField2}|"></span>

that works fine... but in this case I need to perform the th:each for every field name that I have in ${arrayFieldName}.
How can I do this?

Yes, this is called preprocessing in Thymeleaf.  It should look like this:
<tr th:each="row : ${list}">
    <td th:each="field : ${arrayFieldName}" scope="row">
        <span th:text="|${row.__${field}__}|"></span>
    </td>
</tr>

